# How to use or condition in typescript regex?

Tags: regex, typescript, yup

I'm trying to make sure only one type of special character (semi-colon, comma, or space) is used in a string.

e.g this should match as it only uses one type of special character (semi-colon): `https://hello.com/example1;https://hello.com.com/example2;https://hello.com.com/example3`

This should fail as it mixes two types of special characters (space and semi-colon)

`https://hello.com/example1; https://hello.com.com/example2 ;https://hello.com.com/example3`

This is my code - im using the yup schema builder for validation:

```js
const myValidation = yup
.string()
.matches(/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]|[A-Za-z0-9:// \\.]|[A-Za-z0-9://;\\.])+$/, 'Please separate each with a comma, space or semicolon')
.required();
```

When i only have `/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]+$/` it works correctly to only match the string if it has a only a comma as special character: `https://hello.com/example1,https://hello.com.com/example2,https://hello.com.com/example3`

but as soon as i add the other or conditions `/^([A-Za-z0-9://,\\.]|[A-Za-z0-9:// \\.]|[A-Za-z0-9://;\\.])+$/` it starts allowing for semi-colon and space and comma special characters in the string at the same time (the invalid case)

Comment: Maybe you want to use `/^[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+(?=([,;\s])|$)(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+)*$/`? See https://regex101.com/r/nAtBHp/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+(?=([,;\s])|$)(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAtBHp/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+` - one or more ASCII letters, digits, `:`, `/`, `\` or `.` chars
- `(?=([,;\s])|$)` -  a positive lookahead capturing the subsequent `,`, `;` or whitespace into Group 1, or matching end of string
- `(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9:\/\\.]+)*` - zero or more sequences of the Group 1 value and then one or more ASCII letters, digits, `:`, `/`, `\` or `.` chars
- `$` - end of string.